# Why are figures 1-9 written as numbers, but after 9 written in alphabet form?

Tags: orthography, writing-style, numbers, convention

I have tried to research this .. could anyone answer why figures 1-9 are written as digits/numbers and then from 9 onwards they are typed in alphabetical form?

Comment: Please don't write in block capitals. It's considered "loud" by some, and "rude" by others.

Comment: related: 1. [Spelling of small numbers?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/spelling-of-small-numbers) 2. [When to spell out numbers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/when-to-spell-out-numbers)

Comment: When to use numerals and when to spell out the name of a number is a matter of style; there is no single convention. Actually, the more common guideline that style guides give is the opposite— to spell out one through nine or even one through ninety-nine, and use numerals for 10 or 100 or greater.

Comment: Apologies to you once more Mari-Lou A I don't know that was rude .. I have always, previously, made the subject in block capitals to make it stand out more.. I NEVER know it was considered rude. I have learnt.