# Is it "2-8 days" or "two to eight days"?

Tags: grammar, writing-style

When I am writing a book and referring to something that lasts 2-8 days, do I say "*2-8 days*" or "*two to eight days*"? Also, when referring to how much of something I would use, would I say "*2-4 tablespoons*" or "*two to four tablespoons*"?

Comment: In general, you can do it however you want as long as you are consistent about it.  If you're writing for a particular publisher, get the style guide they use and follow that.

Comment: You can't say "2-8" at all vocally. It is said as "two to eight" or "two through eight".

Comment: You should separate numeric ranges using an en dash instead of a hyphen-minus, so *2–8* not *2-8*.  Sometimes it is better to space the operands: *Safe when stored at −10° – +40° C*.

Comment: @tchrist the dash vs. hyphen continually rears its head. For example that punctuation sign is not available on my keyboard, it wasn't until last year that someone on ELU explained the trick. Which I will now reveal; press *Alt* and at the same time press 0151 on the number pad —, once you release the *Alt* key, the dash signs appears magically! My laptop is Aspire; running on Windows Vista (sigh...)

Comment: related: [When to spell out numbers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/when-to-spell-out-numbers), and [Spelling out non-cardinal small numbers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75472/spelling-out-non-cardinal-small-numbers?rq=1,) and [Why do English writers avoid explicit numerals?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/979/why-do-english-writers-avoid-explicit-numerals)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m sorry that Microsoft expects you to remember such a long and complicated, and unmnemonic, a keystroke sequence. On a Mac, you use the ALT key like a shifter and hit  the regular `-` character for an en dash (`–`), and both ALT and SHIFT with the regular `-` for the longer em dash (`—`).

Comment: @tchrist  The irony is that Microsoft calls it a "shortcut"!

Comment: @tchrist an en dash in MS word is Ctrl+Numpad hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid, but imho the numerical format is more succinct and stands out from the surrounding text.

Consider this sentence:

> During my holiday trip, I will spend just 1-2 nights in London followed by 10-15 days touring the rest of Europe, and return by 28th or 29th.

Or some (made up) recipe:

> - 1-2 finely chopped onions
> - 3-5 tsp flour
> - Few pinches of salt

In both these, I think writing out the numbers in long hand will make it excessively verbose.

As a counterexample, consider the lumber size '*two by four*' , representing it as '*2* x *4*' may take a bit of processing for people who parse 'x' symbol as '*into/multiplied by*'. However, when a smaller number is followed by a larger number and separated by '*-*', it's common to read the symbol as '*to*' (unless it's in a mathematical sense).

Comment: +1 for using the word "succinct"! Off-topic, but a good example for consonant clusters. (:

Comment: @Neeku Thanks, that formatting looks much better. Also, oops on the 'its' mistake :P

Answer (score -1):

Both convey the same meaning but the fully written form "two to eight days"/"two to four tablespoons" doesn't leave place to any effort of interpretation: It explains what the dash would stand for.

Comment: This *might* try to answer the question, but it only expresses a personal opinion without providing any reference.

Comment: Also, I didn't downvote!

Comment: @Neeku I tried to expand some more

Comment: This still shows your own personal opinion. Formatting *your own opinion* as quotation, doesn't really improve the quality of your answer at all.

Comment: @Neeku Tried to remove myself from the equation