# Correct usage of numero sign (№): cardinal numbers okay?

Tags: abbreviations, numbers

Can the numero sign (№) only be used to indicate ordinal numbers only, or would it be correct to use it for cardinal numbers as well?

A very specific example: if I write about "the number of males observed in the sample", could I use "№ of males in sample" for a table header? Or is that usage strictly speaking correct only for usages such as "observation № 22"?

Comment: I have seen [this discussion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174639/may-numero-sign-no-be-used-to-indicate-amount), but the answer given there is not completely clear to me…So I'll take the risk of being marked duplicate and revive the discussion.

Comment: Even if you **can**, why would you **want** to? For your example, why not just use "males in sample" or just "males" if you want to shorten it?

Comment: True, it is a slightly concocted example…but it could be that there is also individual information, and "males in sample" could have individual names, followed by columns of age, sex, …. You would then need a "№" or "Number of" column to distinguish. In any case, I see similar constructions sometimes, and always wonder if the usage is correct (even if not stylistically appropriate).

Comment: Fair enough I suppose. I just think that any space you're saving is outweighed by any confusion you might introduce. Alternatively, why not just use the # number symbol?

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but isn't the hash the American English version of the Numero sign? If so, the same question applies.

Comment: In the UK at least, I've seen plenty of uses of the similar "No." (e.g. "No. of males in sample") which do not result in confusion.  Although you should probably avoid it in formal writing and limit its use, as you say, to table headings where it's strictly necessary to save space.  You might find [this lengthy discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=264328) interesting.

Comment: The numero sign (as well as the word _number_, the abbreviation _no._, and the symbol _#_) are not used with ordinal numbers at all—where did you get that idea? When you write “observation № 22 [twenty-two]”, you’re using it with a cardinal number; with an ordinal number, you’d have something like “observation № 22nd [twenty-second]”, which does not make any sense. _[noun] number [cardinal]_ is already equivalent to _[ordinal]th [noun]_. What you really seem to be asking is whether _№_ can be used for _number_ in cases where no numerals are involved at all.

Comment: Saying “observation № 22 [twenty-two]” is ordinal in the sense that it is the  (presumably) 22nd observation in a sequence. It makes no sense to think about "the number of men" in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a universally accepted formal answer to this.  This answer is my own style, which is reflected by Wikipedia.

From Wikipedia's article on the [numero sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign),

> № is a typographic abbreviation for the word *number(s)* indicating an [ordinal numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), especially in names and titles.

Use № only when you are using numerals (not [when the number is spelled out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/979/why-do-english-writers-avoid-explicit-numerals)), and **only when you are referring to the number as an identifier/designation rather than as a quantity**.

So I would advocate *for*:

- Observation № 22
- Now serving № 8
- Insert part № 3 into slot 7

I would advocate *against*:

- № of males in sample 5
- Now serving № eight
- Wow, that was home run № 3!

You also brought up using numero signs in tables.  It is considered acceptable to bend style guidelines when it comes to layout and other graphic design; if "№" fits where "number" does not, feel free to use the shorter version.

(There is also an archaic usage for the numero, in which it may be used [to indicate quantity](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/174641/112762), as "№" does have a definition in which it means "in number," but I've never seen this usage in practice.)

Comment: Thanks, would vote up but cannot…Wikipedia says No is an "abbreviation of the word number(s) _indicating ordinal numeration_" (my emph), which is why "№ of males in sample 5" feels awkward to me, but "Number of males in sample № 5" does not. I agree that lay-out and design allow some leeway.

Comment: @Matthijs you are correct.  I must have read the wikipedia article too hastily; wikipedia actually agrees with my style. I have updated my answer to note that.  Thanks!