# Can you say "Scheduled for 2 days ago"?

Tags: phrases

I'm generating some text that on a website that informs the user when a specific event is scheduled to take place. The temporal information is always relative to the current point in time, e.g. **2 days ago** or **a week from now**. In all cases (past, present and future), could I use the static prefix **Scheduled for (...)**?

Examples:

> Scheduled for a day ago.
>
> Scheduled for 2 weeks ago.
>
> Scheduled for a month from now.
>
> Scheduled for now.

If this is not the proper phrasing I'm welcoming any prefix suggestions that would make more sense =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest some improvements:

- ... scheduled for yesterday.
- ... scheduled for **two** weeks ago - See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/979/why-do-english-writers-avoid-explicit-numerals).
- ... scheduled for a month from now - Exactly one month? maybe "scheduled for about a month from now" would be better.
- ... scheduled for now - Though correct, may be ambiguous. When is "now"? This minute? This hour? Maybe 10 minutes ago?. "... scheduled for 10:00 a.m." may be better.

Comment: Aside your suggestions, would you in general say that "Scheduled for [some time] ago/from now" is correct phrasing?

Comment: @DoubleM: yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, you made some excellent points and I will incorporate them in my project +1

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it would be much clearer to say:

> The event was scheduled to take place [two days ago].

Or perhaps (depending on the type of the event):

> The event was scheduled to occur [two days ago].

Comment: I agree, but in this case the phrase needs to be as concise as possible; the meaning can easily be derived from its context (it's rather clear when you see it). Thanks for pointing it out though.